# Javascript click or tts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web, text-to-speech

i'm trying to make a web aplication than can read text automatically,i have this code:

```
function hablalo()
    {
        var palabra = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Casilla 6 turno E18');
        palabra.lang = "es"
        speechSynthesis.speak(palabra);
    }

    $('#perez').trigger($.Event( "click", { originalEvent: true } ));
```

and so i have a button with the event that call hablalo.

The problem is that when i try to make this, the result is:

```
(index):20 [Deprecation] speechSynthesis.speak() without user activation is no longer allowed since M71, around December 2018. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5687444770914304 for more details
```

I would like a way to simulate a click in chrome or another way to make tts, thanks you. :)

--EDITED

If you know a library that i can use for autoplay tts at load of a webpage, is fine

Comment: Not possible - you'll have to manually click / interact first.

Comment: Consider reading the article they linked. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5687444770914304 --- This still works in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my problem with [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), summary i modify the laucher-flags of chrome in the client's pc adding `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` at the end of route in propertiesof the launcher.

It seems like is imposible to make from code, but this solution is a resignation way.